# The normal closure of a subset is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S$ be a subset of a group $G$, let $N:=\{gsg^{-1}:g\in G,s\in S\}$. This is the smallest normal subgroup containing $S$. But how to show that $N$ is a group? How can I see that $gs^{-1}g^{-1}$ and $g_1s_1g_1^{-1}g_2s_2g_2^{-1}$ are also in $N$?

Comment: This is a case of a mistaken definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might not be a group. For example take $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $S=\{1\}$. For every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have $n+1+(-n)=1$ and so $N=\{1\}$. This is obviously not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Edit:** The normal closure is defined as the subgroup generated by the set $N$ you defined.

Comment: What if $S$ is a group?

Comment: @Alex If $S$ is not normal then your $N$ still isn't a subgroup. For example take $G=S_3$ and $S=\langle (12)\rangle$.